# Wrapper element for for loop

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently expanding my horizon by trying out Vuejs.
I'm creating a navigation with data coming from my Vue instance, and I have the following code:

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item" v-for="navLink in navLinks" :key="navLink.id">
        <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now even though this works perfectly fine, I have seen the following two examples in videos instead:

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <template v-for="navLink in navLinks">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <div v-for="navLink in navLinks" :key="navLink.id">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

I'm asking myself which one of these is best practice.

Now from what I've learned, one should always (if possible) set a **:key** in a for loop. This is not possible on the  tag, therefore I would think this option is the worse.

But what about option 3 and mine? Is there any difference? Is it just personal preference or is there an actual reason on why to choose one or the other.

Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference I spot between the first and the third options is that you'd wrap each list item in an additional div. You don't need those wrappers unless you want to use this nesting for styling purposes.

Your example is perfectly fine. Just make sure ids you use for keys are unique.

Also avoid using `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element and rather add `v-if` on the parent

Answer (score 0):

Yours is fine, all of them indeed are going to work well, but the third one *may* have problems with custom css, since it's a wrapper for the tag.

The template is an alternative as it is stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt).

You've set the key at the li tag, as long as you're following the guide for [mantaining state with keys](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State), it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should always put a `key` property in your for loop.

Say you have nothing to work with for an ID (some `item.name` could potentially be duplicated?) just use this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items)" :key="index">
  {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

`index` in this case is just the index of the `items` array.

Answer (score 0):

So yours will be rendered like:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item" :key="navLink.id">
        <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
    </li>

    ...

    <li class="nav-item" :key="navLink.id">
        <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Whereas the third one will be:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <div :key="navLink.id">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </div>

    ...

    <div :key="navLink.id">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" :href="navLink.url">{{ navLink.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

I would say it's a bit verbose to wrap a `<li>` inside a `<div>` in each one of them.